# copy node where certain attributes are present (or not present)

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I currently have this xsl that is working great

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@Ccy"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This essentially re-writes my XML removing all attributes except Ccy.  However, I now need to include attributes with the name "name" as well.  Id like to either union the attribute names that I would like to keep:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="@Ccy | @name"/>
```

Or, ideally, copy all attributes EXCEPT

```
<xsl:copy-of select="!@BadAttyName"/>
```

Any ideas??

Comment: Looks like I answered my own question.  <xsl:copy-of select="@Ccy | @name"/> seems to work.  For "fun" though, how would copy everything EXCEPT attributes that start with BadAttyName?  <xsl:copy-of select="!@BadAttyName*"/>??

Comment: Could you add an XML sample please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following stylesheets:

**INPUT:**

```
$more input.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a>
  <b Ccy="123" name="test1" BadAttyNameTest="toRemove1" BadAttyNameTestt="toRemovee1" other="hey1">toto</b>
  <b Ccy="456" name="test2" BadAttyNameTest="toRemove2" BadAttyNameTestt="toRemovee2" other="hey2">abc</b>
  <b Ccy="789" name="test3" BadAttyNameTest="toRemove3" BadAttyNameTestt="toRemovee3" other="hey3">uvw</b>
</a>
```

**UNION:**

```
::::::::::::::
inputUnion.xsl
::::::::::::::
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@Ccy | @name"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OUTPUT UNION:**

```
$xsltproc inputUnion.xsl input.xml 
<a>
  <b Ccy="123" name="test1">toto</b>
  <b Ccy="456" name="test2">abc</b>
  <b Ccy="789" name="test3">uvw</b>
</a>
```

It will only copy the union of the attributes `@Ccy | @name`, the other attributes are not taken into account.

**EXCEPT:**

```
::::::::::::::
inputNOT.xsl
::::::::::::::
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*[not(starts-with(name(),'BadAttyName'))]"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OUTPUT EXCEPT:**

```
$xsltproc inputNOT.xsl input.xml 
<a>
  <b Ccy="123" name="test1" other="hey1">toto</b>
  <b Ccy="456" name="test2" other="hey2">abc</b>
  <b Ccy="789" name="test3" other="hey3">uvw</b>
</a>
```

the syntax `@*[not(starts-with(name(),'BadAttyName'))]` will take all attributes that satisfies the condition in the brackets. The condition is all elements that do not start with `BadAttyName`, this is created by combining `not()` and `starts-with()`.

Answer (score 2):

XSLT 2.0 allows

```
<xsl:copy-of select="@* except @badAttName"/>
```

and of course it also allows

```
<xsl:copy-of select="@* except @*[startswith(name(), 'badAttName')]"/>
```

But for this particular case, using `@*[not(....)]` works just as well.

Comment: Thanks for the taking the time to answer Michael!

Answer (score 2):

XPath 2 and later (which is the expression language you use with XSLT 2 and later) does have an `except` operator so you can use e.g. `<xsl:copy-of select="@* except @foo"/>` to copy all attributes except the `foo` attribute or e.g. `<xsl:copy-of select="@* except (@foo, @bar)"/>` to copy all attributes except the `foo` and `bar` one.

As you want to exclude attributes starting with a certain prefix you could use `<xsl:copy-of select="@* except @*[matches(local-name(), '^BadAttyName')]"/>` although the already suggested solution negating the condition with `<xsl:copy-of select="@*[not(matches(local-name(), '^BadAttyName'))]"/>` is more compact and easier in that case probably.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying martin